# Remove files with same contents with shell script

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I have to write a script that removes duplicate regular files (files with the same contents) from the files passed as arguments. Also I have to retain the file with the oldest time stamp. If there is a tie in time stamp, I can choose one arbitrarily.

For example:

> If I have three files A B and C with same contents inside them and also A and B have same time stamp then I have to keep A or B and delete another file along with file C.

What I have done so far:

```
if["$#" -1e 1];then
echo "Usage `basename $0` has $# arguments. Need to use atleast 2 arguments to compare the files"
while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
if [ -f "$1" -a -f "$2" ]; then
[cmp -s $1 $2 ] && [ "$1" -nt "$2" ] && rm $1 || rm $2
fi 
shift
done
```

But it is not working as intended. Any ideas?

Comment: are you sure it's bourne shell? i am not aware that bourne shell supports array. should it be bourne shell, or can it be bash? if bash is acceptable, some solution can be raised. try to replace your code to run in bash, and see if it works there.

Comment: Yeah I have to use Bourne shell. I am new to Bourne so I was not aware arrays are not supported. Thank you for the information.

Comment: let me correct it a bit. depending on your system, `sh` does not necessarily point to bourne shell. in my system, it points to dash. i am pretty sure all debian derived systems point to dash. red hat systems might do differently. you might not do what you think you should do, and strict requirement of using bourne shell doesn't sound too reasonable in many cases.

Comment: Best to review the limited feature set of Bourne Shell (particularly the limited syntax available to the `for` loop).. Maybe at http://grymoire.com/Unix/Sh.html . AND are you sure? `bash`=`Bourne again shell`, so only the oldest, creakiest stuff still uses original Bourne shell. Good luck!

Comment: I am using terminal window with Ubuntu in my c9.io

Comment: then you have bash, and `sh` is dash.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have any recommended links for `dash`. Good luck!

Comment: some more background. dash is almost only used for scripts that are needed to boot up linux. so the goal of this shell is 1. fast boot, 2. fast run, 3. minimalistic. it's designed with clearly set of functionalities in mind and it might not give you enough strength to handle your task easily. if you are assigned to do such thing, and you are not sure what's the rationale, you'd better figure this out and see how necessary is that.

Comment: Do you have to use posix-standard commands? Posix diff doesn't have a `-q` option.

Comment: Yeah I have to use  posix-standard commands but I was unaware that -q option is not valid. Thank you for information.

Comment: Doing this in a language which doesn't have arrays, is possible, but cumbersome. I strongly suggest that you switch to a different programming language. BTW, you don't need to do a pairwise diff on the files. It is enough to calculate the MD5 and size of each file, and if you encounter another file with the same MD5 and size, you **may** for the safe side diff only those for the safe side, though in practice, if MD5 and size are the same, it's nearly sure that the contents will also be the same.

Comment: I have changed my code based on sh shell in Unix.

Answer (score 0):

Your `[cmp -s $1 $2 ]` command should definitely not work. The `[` symbol is a symlink to the `test` command (see `man test`), not a generic wrapper for conditions. If you want the

```
[ "$1" -nt "$2" ] && rm $1 || rm $2
```

commands to run on the condition that the `cmp` command exits 0 (i.e. no difference is found in the files), you can simply do:

```
cmp -s $1 $2 && [ "$1" -nt "$2" ] && rm $1 || rm $2
```

However, I would change a few things here. I see you're quoting `$1` and `$2` in some places but not others. If they need to be quoted for the `test` command (because of the danger of globbing or word splitting), you should just quote them everywhere.

***Most importantly***, there's a danger in the string of `&&`s and `||`s you're using. Presumably you expect that nothing would be deleted if the files are different from one another, whereas the way you have it, `$2` will be deleted if `cmp` exits nonzero.
Try running the command `false && false && false || echo hello` in a shell. You will see it outputs `hello`.

The same applies for `true && true && false || echo hello`. The latter is the equivalent of if `$1` were newer than `$2` but the `rm` command somehow failed to delete `$1`--it would proceed straight to trying to delete `$2`.
Since the `&&` operator has higher precedence that `||`, if there's a nonzero exit code anywhere in that string of `&&`-connected statements, the statement after the `||` *will* be executed.

I would do this instead:

```
if cmp -s "$1" "$2"; then
    if [ "$1" -nt "$2" ]; then
        rm "$1"
    else
        rm "$2"
    fi
fi
```